# Is the Sleep operation no longer used in VBscript?

Tags: vbscript

The "Sleep" command as stated in many places over the internet (including here on this forum) DOES NOT WORK. Is it now an obsolete command?

I am writing the VBScript code like this:

```
sub button1_onclick()
Wscript.Sleep 1000
div1.innerHTML = textbox1.value
end sub
```

It should wait 1 second and then execute that simple command. This is an utterly simple statement but it does not work. Plain and simple. It comes up with an error every time saying:

> Object Required: 'Wscript'

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A 1 second delay after the button is clicked, before it responds? Is this a requirement?

Comment: @Daniel Cook: Yes, I was just trying to create a delay before the next operation in the procedure. This code was only a really simple bit of stuff to illustrate what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096168/249624) is absolutely correct about context being the key here. Although you don't have the `WScript` method available, you do have the full browser DOM, including the [`window.setTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. With VBScript, the semantics of passing code to `setTimeout` are a little bit different than JavaScript, but it's still possible:

```
Sub button1_onclick()
    window.setTimeout GetRef("Delayed"), 1000
End Sub

Sub Delayed()
    div1.innerHTML = textbox1.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you Cheran... that was the problem I was having. It was that I was trying to use the JavaScript syntax of setTimeout. I will try this when I get time. I have been using w3schools.com mostly and they didn't mention the timeout function. I could not find it anywhere else either.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to (ab)use `ping` (if you want to avoid an additional script):

```
Sub Sleep(seconds)
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " _
    & seconds+1, 0, True
End Sub
```

`ping` sends echo requests in (roughly) 1 second intervals, so you can get an `n`-second delay by sending `n+1` echo requests.

Comment: Looks like an interesting way to manipulate an external source. I think the setTimeout syntax was all I really needed though in the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

When run from a browser, VBScript code does not have a Wscript object. This is only for stand-alone VBS. As such, Wscript.Sleep isn't obsolete, it just doesn't work in a browser without a work around.

[This thread](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/wscript-sleep-html-help-53532232.html#53532612) suggests a potential work around. The rest of this post comes from the entry by mayayana on the linked page:

If your security can allow WScript.Shell to run
you can do it this way -

Script sub in webpage:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub Sleep(NumberSeconds)
Dim SH, Ret
Set SH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Ret = SH.Run("sleeper.vbs " & NumberSeconds, , True)
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

In the same folder as the webpage, put a file named
sleeper.vbs and put this code into it:

```
Dim Arg
on error resume next
Arg = WScript.Arguments(0) * 1000
WScript.sleep Arg
```

You can then call something like:

`Sleep 5` '-- pauses 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried that and to be honest it is too long winded and it would not be acceptable for a college project. I can't start playing with the security features to get the program to work. It is still not working anyway. Is there any other way to implement a timer into VBscript? I tried setTimeOut but that does not seem to work in this language, only javascript. I hate VBscript btw... but this is the language of choice for the college unfortunately :(