# VBS Check internet and delay script until ready

Tags: vbscript, ping, delayed-execution

I got a HTA application that runs when the user log on..

The problem is sometimes the HTA file opens to quickly, before the internet is ready and fails to load some of the scripts that need internet connection..

So my plan is to add a ping test before I call the scripts and then pause calls until the internet connection is ready..

Update:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Kiosk</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="Kiosk Launcher"
    ID="kiosklauncher"
    ICON="data/icon.ico"
    VERSION="1.0"
    CONTEXTMENU = "no"
    BORDER="none"
    INNERBORDER = "no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
    SCROLL="no"/>

<script Language="VBScript">
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Dim Msg_Connected,Msg_NOT_Connected
Msg_Connected = "<h5><font color=""white""><strong>Starter Kiosk<strong></font></h5>"
        
Msg_NOT_Connected = "<h5><font color=""RED""><strong>Error no internet<strong></font></h5>"
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sub Window_OnLoad()
Dim MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,ws
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    window.resizeTo screen.availWidth/4,screen.availHeight/4
    window.moveTo screen.availWidth/2.7,screen.availHeight/2.5
'Call Shortcut()
MyLoop = True
While MyLoop
    strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
    ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
            MyLoop = False
            DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_Connected
        Call Execute("SomeProgram.exe")
        Call Execute("BatScripts.bat")
        Call Sleep(1)
        Call RefreshExplorer
        Call Execute("AnotherProram.exe")
        Call Sleep(1)
        Call Execute("Launcher.bat")              
        call test()
            Exit for
        Else
            DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_NOT_Connected
        End If
    Next
    Sleep(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
Wend
End Sub
    '-----------------------------Sleep-----------------------------------------
    Sub Sleep(seconds)
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " _
        & seconds+1, 0, True
    End Sub
    '-----------------------------TEST-----------------------------------------
    sub test()
    Window.Close
    end sub
    '----------------------------Execute---------------------------------------
    Sub Execute(Program)
        set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        ' shell.ShellExecute "application", "arguments", "path", "verb", window
        shell.ShellExecute ""&Program&"",,"data\", "runas", 0
        set shell=nothing
    End sub
        '-----------------------------RefreshExplorer-----------------------------------
    Function RefreshExplorer() 
        dim strComputer, objWMIService, colProcess, objProcess  
        strComputer = "." 
        'Get WMI object  
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _  
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")  
        Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'explorer.exe'") 
        For Each objProcess in colProcess 
        objProcess.Terminate() 
        Next  
    End Function

</script>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="main">
        <center><h2 style="text-align: center;">Kiosk Launcher</h2></center>
        <center><div><img src="data/preloader.gif" class="preloader-scale" draggable="false" unselectable="on"></div></center>
        <center><h4>Please wait</h4></center>
        <center><span id="DataArea"></span></center>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps if I can get it to work.. When I copy&paste the script into my HTA file i get error: Variable not defined "wscript" Don't know how I fix that..

Comment: "Copy and Paste" without modification is never the way to go about building a script, first understand what it's doing and integrate from there. The important part is the use of a loop with a delay to check the connection, you're already checking the connection you just need to run it in a loop and break the loop on a successful connection.

Comment: Like I said:
"without really any vbs coding skills, this is beyond my light editing skills."

Comment: In which case, you either need to employ someone to code it for you or you have some learning to do. Either way [so] is not a code writing service, we are here to help provide answers to clearly defined problems, which is more difficult when the OP doesn't understand the subject they are asking about. That duplicate gives a clear example of how to loop to check a connection. If you can't implement it that isn't a problem we can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this answer here [Error: Object required: 'wscript' in HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476304/error-object-required-wscript-in-hta?answertab=active#tab-top)

The HTA engine doesn't provide a `WScript` object, so things like `WScript.Quit` or `WScript.Sleep` or `Wscript.Echo` don't work in HTAs.

To programmatically exit from an HTA use `Self.Close` or `window.Close`.

For replacing the `Sleep` method see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13096063/1630171).

---

I made a little example for you to check the connection and i replaced

the `wscript.echo` (dosen't work as i said above) by this `<span id="DataArea"></span>`

And here is the whole HTA :

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Network Diagnostics And Checking Internet Connection by Hackoo 2020</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
 Application ID = "Check_Internet_Connection"
 APPLICATIONNAME = "Check_Internet_Connection"
 BORDER="THIN"
 BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
 CAPTION = "Yes"
 CONTEXTMENU = "Yes"
 ICON = "nslookup.exe"
 INNERBORDER="NO"
 MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
 MINIMIZEBUTTON="YES"
 SCROLL="NO"
 SELECTION="NO
 SHOWINTASKBAR = "Yes"
 SINGLEINSTANCE = "Yes"
 SYSMENU = "Yes"
/>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size: 10x;
        color: #49403B;
        background: LightGreen;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<script Language="VBScript">
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Dim Msg_Connected,Msg_NOT_Connected
Msg_Connected = "<Marquee DIRECTION=""Right"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""6"" BEHAVIOR=""ALTERNATE"">"&_
        "<h2><font color=""GREEN""><strong>You Are Now Connected To The Internet !<strong></font></h2></Marquee><br><br>"&_
        "<img src=""https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite%2FBoogieDown_GIF-1f2be97208316867da7d3cf5217c2486da3c2fe6.gif""></img>"
        
Msg_NOT_Connected = "<Marquee DIRECTION=""Right"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""6"" BEHAVIOR=""ALTERNATE"">"&_
        "<h3><font color=""RED""><strong>You Are Not Connected to the Internet ... We are trying to establish again your connection<strong></font></h3></Marquee>"
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow( widthX, heightY )
    self.ResizeTo widthX, heightY 
    self.MoveTo (screen.Width - widthX)/2, (screen.Height - heightY)/2
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sub Window_OnLoad()
Dim MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,ws
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
CenterWindow 800,600
Call Shortcut()
MyLoop = True
While MyLoop
    strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
    ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
            MyLoop = False
            DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_Connected
            WAN_IP.InnerHTML = "<h2><font color=""GREEN""><strong> WAN IP : " & Get_WAN_IP & "<strong></font></h2>"
            SayIt()
            'Call MyProgram() ' You can call all your Programs here after the connection has been established !
            Exit for
        Else
            DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_NOT_Connected
            ws.run "%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe -skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI"
        End If
    Next
    Sleep(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
Wend
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sub Sleep(seconds)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " & seconds,0,True
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Get_WAN_IP()
Dim http
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )
http.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
http.Send
Get_WAN_IP= http.responseText  
End Function
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SayIt()
Dim fso,WaveFile,ws
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WaveFile = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\NetworkMonitorII.gadget\media\established.wav")
If fso.FileExists(WaveFile) Then
    Play(WaveFile)
    Sleep(5)
    Play("http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream")
Else
    CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak "You are Connected to the internet"
    Sleep(5)
    Play("http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream")
End If
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Play(URL)
    Dim ws,fso,f,TempName,TempFile,TempFolder
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Tempname = fso.GetTempName
    TempFolder = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    TempFile = TempFolder & "\" & Tempname & ".vbs"
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(Tempfile,2,True)
    f.Writeline     "Call Play(" & chr(34) & URL & chr(34) & ")"
    f.Writeline "Sub Play(URL)"
    f.Writeline "Set Sound = CreateObject(""WMPlayer.OCX"")"
    f.Writeline "Sound.URL = URL"
    f.Writeline "Sound.settings.volume = 100"                               
    f.Writeline "Sound.Controls.play"                                     
    f.Writeline "do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0"                
    f.Writeline     "wscript.sleep 100"                                       
    f.Writeline "loop"                                                    
    f.Writeline "wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000" 
    f.Writeline "End Sub"
    f.close
    ws.run Tempfile
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Stop_Playing()
    Dim Command,ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /C Taskkill /IM ""wscript.exe"" /F >nul 2>&1"
    ws.run Command,0,True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_OnUnload()
    Call Stop_Playing()
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub Shortcut()
dim shell,DesktopPath,Link,CurrentFolder,FullName,arrFN,HTA_Name
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CurrentFolder = shell.CurrentDirectory
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
FullName = replace(Check_Internet_Connection.commandLine,chr(34),"")  
arrFN=split(FullName,"\")  
HTA_Name = arrFN(ubound(arrFN))
Link = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(HTA_Name)
Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Link & ".lnk")
link.Description = HTA_Name
link.IconLocation = "nslookup.exe"
link.TargetPath = CurrentFolder & "\" & HTA_Name
link.WorkingDirectory = CurrentFolder
Link.HotKey = "CTRL+ALT+C"
link.Save
end Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(FileName)
    Dim Result, i
    Result = FileName
    i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
    If ( i > 0 ) Then
        Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
    End If
    GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
<body>
    <center>
        <span id="DataArea"></span>
        </br></br>
        <span id="WAN_IP"></span>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***Edit : 28/08/2020 @ 12:02***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Kiosk</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="Kiosk Launcher"
    ID="kiosklauncher"
    ICON="data/icon.ico"
    VERSION="1.0"
    CONTEXTMENU = "no"
    BORDER="none"
    INNERBORDER = "no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
    SCROLL="no"/>

<script Language="VBScript">
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Dim Msg_Connected,Msg_NOT_Connected
Msg_Connected = "<h5><font color=""white""><strong>Starter Kiosk<strong></font></h5>"
        
Msg_NOT_Connected = "<h5><font color=""RED""><strong>Error no internet<strong></font></h5>"
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sub Window_OnLoad()
    Dim MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    window.resizeTo screen.availWidth/4,screen.availHeight/4
    window.moveTo screen.availWidth/2.7,screen.availHeight/2.5
    MyLoop = True
    While MyLoop
        strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
        For Each objStatus in objPing
            If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
                MyLoop = False
                DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_Connected
'Call Execute("SomeProgram.exe")
'Call Execute("BatScripts.bat")
                Call Sleep(1)
'Call RefreshExplorer
'Call Execute("AnotherProram.exe")
                Call Sleep(1)
'Call Execute("Launcher.bat")              
'call test()
                MsgBox  "You are now connected to the Internet ! " & vbCrLf &_
                "And The splash screen will exit now after you clicked on this Message Box !"
                Call CloseHTA()
'Exit for
            Else
                DataArea.InnerHTML = Msg_NOT_Connected
            End If
        Next
        Sleep(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
    Wend
End Sub
'-----------------------------Sleep-----------------------------------------
Sub Sleep(seconds)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " & seconds+1,0, True
End Sub
'-----------------------------TEST-----------------------------------------
Sub CloseHTA()
    Self.Close
End sub
'----------------------------Execute---------------------------------------
Sub Execute(Program)
    Dim Shell ' You forget here to declare the variable Shell so be careful
    set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' shell.ShellExecute "application", "arguments", "path", "verb", window
    shell.ShellExecute ""&Program&"",,"data\", "runas", 0
    set shell=nothing
End sub
'-----------------------------RefreshExplorer-----------------------------------
Function RefreshExplorer() 
    dim strComputer, objWMIService, colProcess, objProcess  
    strComputer = "." 
'Get WMI object  
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _  
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")  
    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'explorer.exe'") 
    For Each objProcess in colProcess 
        objProcess.Terminate() 
    Next  
End Function
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="main">
        <center><h2 style="text-align: center;">Kiosk Launcher</h2></center>
        <center><div><img src="data/preloader.gif" class="preloader-scale" draggable="false" unselectable="on"></div></center>
        <center><h4>Please wait</h4></center>
        <center><span id="DataArea"></span></center>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping you would see the topic Hackoo.. I have been playing around with the script.. And Think I can make something work with it.. The only problems I've noticed is the script I use to center and rezise the HTA windows based on resolution breaks, when I add the script it complains about Variable "widthX" is not defined. I have added my source in topic..

Comment: @Xenosis Re-check it now i updated the HTA for you !

Comment: Okay I now had some time to mess with the script now.. And I have to say it's giving me lots a trouble. When I add the ping script to my working Splash.hta everything else seems to break with undefined variables.. Boh my window resize based on resolution and my execute programs script breaks.. Why does it mess with my working code?? I've updated topic with my Splash.hta file..

Comment: @Xenosis You forget to declare `Dim Shell` and check the edited code ! and If you can zip all your files batch and HTA and post it as link on your next comment, i want to try your whole project !